# Flying from Venice to New York via Amsterdam - 50 minutes transfer time

Tags: short-connections, ams, klm

I am Italian with an Italian passport and I've booked a ticket Venice-New York via Amsterdam. I'm reading all possible discouraging things about having only 50 minutes to catch the connection, like an interview I need to take before actually being issued the boarding card for the flight to New York. The ticket is a single KLM ticket, but the second part of the journey is operated in partnership with Delta.

I'm pretty worried about missing the connection.

Answer (score 2):

50 minutes is KLM's minimum connection time for intercontinental connections at Amsterdam. The fact that they're willing to sell you the ticket indicates that they think it is at least *common* for passengers to be able to make it. After all, if you *don't* make it, they will have to pay to rebook you on another flight and pay EU compensation.

That being said, flying close to the minimum connection means that there *is* a realistic risk that you don't make it and have to be rebooked -- in particular if your incoming flight is even slightly delayed.

You may wish to call KLM and enquire whether it is possible to change your booking to one with a longer connection. They may or may not agree to that without charging exorbitant change fees.

Tell the cabin crew on the flight from Venice that you have a short connection and ask if they can offer any help with making the connection.

---

There's no *interview* you need to pass through in Amsterdam, and you will almost certainly get a boarding card for the transatlantic leg when you check in in Venice.

You need to pass through outbound passport control in Amsterdam, but that is quite painless when you're traveling with an EU passport. Some queueing can occur, though.

There's also generally an additional security check *at the gate* when departing on a flight to the US. But it's not likely to hold you up a lot; by the time you come running to the gate everyone else will already have been processed. And if you do hit a line there, they're not going to close the doors and depart while they're still processing passengers *for that flight specifically*.

Comment: Do you mean, *they're **not** going to close the doors while they're still processing passengers for that flight specifically*?

Comment: @krubo: Whoops, right. What nonsense that was.

Comment: The additional US security check at the gate sometimes involves a short interview (who packed your bags, etc).

Answer (score 0):

It’s also possible that with any delay on the inbound flight into Amsterdam the passenger manages to make the connection but their hold luggage doesn’t - this has happened to my partner when flying KLM. I’d follow @Henning Makholm’s advice and call the airline to see if you can get a longer connection time.