# Have I got enough time to make this connecting flight from London to Toronto Pearson via Amsterdam?

Tags: airport-transfer, amsterdam, ams, toronto, jet-airways

I haven't flown much so any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

I booked a flight from London Heathrow to Toronto Pearson which has a layover at Schiphol airport, Amsterdam.

The first leg is with KLM which lands at Schiphol at 11:00am. The second leg is with Jet Airways which departs at 12:10pm.

I checked Jet Airways website and apparently one of their 'Through check-in partners' is KLM so I'm presuming that'll make baggage/security easier?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this on one ticket? Then I wouldn't worry. First, they will observe the official minimal connecting times, and second, it's their responsibility to get you to your destination.

Comment: Hi npl, yes I booked in all in one go and on the Jet Airways eTicket it displays both sections of the journey. It also shows both legs on the KLM website too which I guess is a good sign!

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flying from Venice to New York via Amsterdam - 50 minutes transfer time](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/115248/flying-from-venice-to-new-york-via-amsterdam-50-minutes-transfer-time)

Comment: Not a real duplicate as Venice is in the Schengen area (so exit check is needed) while London is not, (no passport control needed) also not sure about security, as the USA expect extra checks which Canada may not want.

Answer (score 2):

You should have enough time except the following happens:

- Your first flight is delayed for more than 20-30 minutes
- Your first flight is cancelled

Your bags should get checked through, but ask them again at the check-in counter in London, just to be sure.

After landing you are going to walk up to 25 minutes to your departure gate. Boarding is normally up to 15 minutes prior to departure.

I would still advise you to proceed quickly to the departure gate and ensure, you have the boardingpasses for your second flight on hand.

If your first flight gets delayed, tell the cabincrew, so they can arrange for you to be passed through the airport quicker.

If everything fails, you get a new flight organized by the Airline you booked with.

Comment: Why would there be passport control in this instance? Non-Schengen to non-Schengen transfer.

Comment: your right, i usually fly there from Zürich, i will edit my answer

Answer (score 2):

I did a similar thing at Schipol last year.

I was traveling on a single ticket, and when I checked in at Heathrow I was given my boarding pass for both flights.

I had 80 minutes to transfer, but we were delayed 30 minutes at Heathrow.

On arrival in Amsterdam We had a 10 minute taxi plus the time it took to disembark

I also had a 25 minute walk accross the airport.

I just made the airplane, unfortunately my luggage did not.

Schipol is well set up for transfers.  But you are dependant on everything working well.

If you are traveling on a single ticket everything would be OK and you would be accommodated on an alternative flight.

If you have to collect your bags and recheck in it won't be possible